# Remote development (from PhpStorm with JetBrains Gateway) without internet possible?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, remote-access, development-environment, jetbrains-ide

Here is my working context;

- no internet (I use my company's intranet)
- Linux CentOS 7.9 remote server with my source files
- PhpStorm 2021.3.2 on my development PC

My wish is to develop on my PC on remote sources. Your new JetBrains Gateway solution seems to meet my expectations on paper.

However, in practice, I have the impression that it is not possible to use this solution without internet ? Indeed, the connection process stops on this failure:

[image: Failed to download JetBrains client]

Looks like your solution is trying to download an IDE client to install on my machine. Which from my point of view is a weird behavior because I already have a client to install on my machine: PhpStorm. Why not use my PhpStorm client already installed on my machine ?

Thank you for your reply

Comment: Maybe your machine at the time is not powerful enough so using a remote machine is more suitable.

Comment: *"Your new JetBrains Gateway solution"* ... *"Looks like your solution"* If you want to address this to JetBrains then why don't you contact JetBrains directly? You know -- "PhpStorm | Help | Contact Support..." or https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731

Comment: Bro, just use the a local JetBrains installation. JetBrains Gateway is meant for remote development, i.e you have to have Internet connection. It is meant as a solution for companies with lots of juniors or freelance developers with low-powered pcs (a.k.a thin clients) and good internet connection, in order to facilitate portability and working from anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

The "Jetbrains Client" mentioned in the error message is not for your local machine, but for the Linux server:

> Once the IDE version and project directory are selected, Gateway will download the IDE to the remote server, unpack it, and launch it with your project loaded.

It acts on the remote server as a "backend IDE" to which the client on your local machine connects:

> The JetBrains Client runs locally and provides the user interface for the IDE backend.

You would not even require the full PHPStorm IDE, the Jetbrains Gateway is a standalone app that comes with a "thin client" that can connect to the backend IDE:

> This whole process is managed by JetBrains Gateway, a new, compact, standalone app that provides everything you need to get started with remote development. Since it’s standalone, it’s the only thing you need to install locally to start working and is ideal for less powerful laptops and in cases where a full IDE install isn’t desired.

See https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2021/12/03/dive-into-jetbrains-gateway/ for a more detailed look at how it works.

To answer your question: it is not possible to use Jetbrains Gateway without an internet connection.